# GWT editors and get/set value

Tags: java, gwt, editor

I have following editor class, and I'm curious what's wrong with it. When running, it does correctly set the right radio button as selected. However, when flushing the top level editor, getValue is never called, and my object's property never get updated. Here's the code (hint - modified ValueListBox):

```java
    public class ValueRadioList<T> extends FlowPanel implements
        HasConstrainedValue<T>, LeafValueEditor<T>, ValueChangeHandler<Boolean> {

    private final List<T> values = new ArrayList<T>();
    private final Map<Object, Integer> valueKeyToIndex =
            new HashMap<Object, Integer>();

    private final String name;
    private final Renderer<T> renderer;
    private final ProvidesKey<T> keyProvider;

    private T value;

    public ValueRadioList(Renderer<T> renderer) {
        this(renderer, new SimpleKeyProvider<T>());
    }

    public ValueRadioList(Renderer<T> renderer, ProvidesKey<T> keyProvider) {
        super();
        this.name = DOM.createUniqueId();
        this.keyProvider = keyProvider;
        this.renderer = renderer;
    }

    private void addValue(T value) {
        Object key = keyProvider.getKey(value);
        if (valueKeyToIndex.containsKey(key)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Duplicate value: " + value);
        }

        valueKeyToIndex.put(key, values.size());
        values.add(value);
        RadioButton radio = new RadioButton(name, renderer.render(value));
        radio.addValueChangeHandler(this);
        add(radio);
        assert values.size() == getWidgetCount();
    }

    @Override public HandlerRegistration addValueChangeHandler(
            ValueChangeHandler<T> handler) {
        return addHandler(handler, ValueChangeEvent.getType());
    }

    @Override public T getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    @Override public void onValueChange(ValueChangeEvent<Boolean> event) {
        int selectedIndex = -1;
        for (int i = 0, l = getWidgetCount(); i < l; i++) {
            if (((RadioButton) getWidget(i)).getValue()) {
                selectedIndex = i;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (selectedIndex < 0) {
            return; // Not sure why this happens during addValue
        }
        T newValue = values.get(selectedIndex);
        setValue(newValue, true);
    }

    @Override public void setAcceptableValues(Collection<T> newValues) {
        values.clear();
        valueKeyToIndex.clear();
        clear();

        for (T nextNewValue : newValues) {
            addValue(nextNewValue);
        }

        updateRadioList();
    }

    @Override public void setValue(T value) {
        setValue(value, false);
    }

    @Override public void setValue(T value, boolean fireEvents) {
        if (value == this.value
                || (this.value != null && this.value.equals(value))) {
            return;
        }

        T before = this.value;
        this.value = value;
        updateRadioList();

        if (fireEvents) {
            ValueChangeEvent.fireIfNotEqual(this, before, value);
        }
    }

    private void updateRadioList() {
        Object key = keyProvider.getKey(value);
        Integer index = valueKeyToIndex.get(key);
        if (index == null) {
            addValue(value);
        }

        index = valueKeyToIndex.get(key);
        ((RadioButton) getWidget(index)).setValue(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Solved it, my POJO missed a setter for that field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it, my POJO missed a setter for that field.